# group_concat concat sum if dates are equal

Tags: mysql

I have this group_concat with concat that is working fine except I need to find a way to get the same results but sum(pest_count) where scout_date is the same. The $scout_date is coming from a dropdown that is looking at the same table for the dates so it has the format 2014-03-13. Thanks for looking.

```
"SELECT group_concat(concat('<div class=\"',pest_name,'\">',pest_count,' ',pest_name,'</div>')   SEPARATOR ' ') pests,
  card_id,
  card_type,
  top_y,
  left_x,
  scout_date FROM scout_logpestnum WHERE custnum='$custnum' AND locationname='$locationname' AND scoutlogname = '$scoutlogname' AND date(scout_date) ='$scout_date' 
GROUP BY
   card_id,
   card_type,
   top_y,
   left_x,
   scout_date"
```

Here's my object that echos the result

```
<?php echo $obj['pests']; ?>
```

Here's my table data

```
pest_name   pest_count  card_id   card_type top_y   left_x   scout_date
Aphids      2              1       yellcard  652    703     2014-3-13 15:59:54
Thrips      4              1       yellcard  652    703     2014-3-13 15:59:54
Thrips      2              2       bluecard  754    707     2014-3-13 15:59:54
Thrips      1              3       yellcard  531    616     2014-3-13 15:59:54
Thrips      1              5       yellcard   80    613     2014-3-13 15:59:54
Aphids      1              1       yellcard  652    703     2014-3-13 16:00:04
Thrips      2              1       yellcard  652    703     2014-3-13 16:00:04
```

Here's what the query will return now for card_id 1

```
 2 Aphids
 4 Thrips
 1 Aphids
 2 Thrips
```

Here' the desired result

Here's what I want in the end for each pest_name and pest_count at each card. This would be card_id 1 for the date 2014-3-13

```
3 Aphids
6 Thrips
```

Here's my final version for now thanks to John for the much needed help.

```
SELECT card_id,left_x,top_y,card_type, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<div class=\"',pest_name,'\">',pest_count,' ',pest_name,'</div>')   SEPARATOR ' ') pests FROM(
SELECT card_id,left_x,top_y,card_type, pest_name AS pest_name, sum(pest_count) AS pest_count, scout_date
FROM scout_logpestnumtest
GROUP BY pest_name,card_id, date(scout_date)
) as t
  GROUP by card_id
```

Comment: when you say here's my table data.. is that how the data is in the database right now? or is that what you get when you run the above query?

Comment: That's my table as it is. The query above returns the desired result that I posted but it repeats instead of summing the pest_counts for the identical pest_name's on the same scout_date.

Comment: ok I think I figured out your problem.. check the answer I gave and let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is group by the DATE of the datetime field instead of including the timestamp.. when you do `DATE(scout_date)` it will ignore the timestamp and just group the date.. so since thats the only field that is different that would cause the grouping to show 4 instead of 2 results it seems like thats the problem there.

```
SELECT 
    group_concat(
        concat('<div class=\"',pest_name,'\">',pest_count,' ',pest_name,'</div>')   SEPARATOR ' '
    ) pests,
    card_id,
    card_type,
    top_y,
    left_x,
    scout_date 
FROM scout_logpestnum 
WHERE custnum='$custnum' 
    AND locationname='$locationname' 
    AND scoutlogname = '$scoutlogname' 
    AND date(scout_date) ='$scout_date' 
GROUP BY card_id, DATE(scout_date)
```

---

**EDIT**:
my recommendation is to sum the data first then do the concat afterwards like this. see [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc8ca/16) for example

```
SELECT
    card_id, 
    group_concat(
        concat('<div class=\"',pest_name,'\">',pest_count,' ',pest_name,'</div>')   SEPARATOR ' '
    ) pests 
FROM(
    SELECT 
        pest_name AS pest_name, 
        sum(pest_count) AS pest_count, 
        card_id,
        card_type,
        top_y,
        left_x,
        scout_date
    FROM scout_logpestnum
    WHERE custnum='$custnum' 
        AND locationname='$locationname' 
        AND scoutlogname = '$scoutlogname' 
        AND date(scout_date) ='$scout_date'
    GROUP BY card_id, card_type, top_y, left_x, date(scout_date)
) as t
GROUP BY card_id
```

---

**EDIT:** this [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc8ca/11) shows the data by card id.. so my edit should work with the above query.. I removed the group concat just so you can read it better... it groups by the card and the name and the date so that way you have the correct number of `div`'s returned.

Comment: It shows the actual values or each pest_count instead of summing the pest_count. 2 Aphids
 4 Thrips
 1 Aphids
 2 Thrips

Comment: then thats probably because you are doing `concat` on the name and count first before adding them up... group concat wont concat two different numbers together

Comment: ok I just edited with something that should work... you should do the concat after you sum the data together... so do a sub select which gets the numbers correct then concat it together in your div

Comment: That sums all the same pest_names's regardless of card_id. So if I have a card_id of 2 on the same scout_date those get summed also to the same numbers for a grand total instead of broke down by card_id.

Comment: thats probably because I didn't have all of the groups in there. edited

Comment: error as in you cannot connect to the page? or theres a syntax error? it was working lastnight.. and i can't connect to fiddle right now... seems like their site is down. try adding the `card_id` in the GROUP BY

Comment: fiddle is up! this is what im getting when i run it... http://screencast.com/t/q14drTRIeY

Comment: I just edited again...  it will group concat everything for your card_id together.. this is what is returned  (http://screencast.com/t/j0JViy486  )... i also updated the first fiddle link to the most recent fiddle

Comment: You are a star dude! I made a few tweaks to yours and it appears to be summing properly and I'm getting the proper positions.  I posted the code I ended up with.

Comment: It may need some more adjustments. I'm testing on full database and getting different result. I'll post back after I make sure I put everything back correctly.

Comment: thanks, let me know what you need tweaked... to be honest it would be best if I had more info to work off of.. as in the custname, locationname.. etc.. that way I can use the same query.. basically I'm writing the query and then adding in the additional stuff you had which could not work since I can't test it.

Comment: I finally got back to this and your code is good to go. I was using a test database and forgot to change the JQuery load on my page back to my actual database. I want to thank you very much for your time and patience during my quest.

Comment: of course. thank you for getting back to it and accepting the post! good luck